# Localized entities in database

Tags: asp.net-core, design-patterns, database-design, localization, translation

I'm developing a ASP.NET Core MVC application and need to design Multilanguage values for entities. There is a lot information how to support localization in UI pages using .resx. I'm looking for some common pattern how to support localization for entities (not for static content on web page), that can be edited by user.

Let say there is a simple dictionary in database table with Statuses

```
Id     Name
----------------------------------------------
1      Not processed
2      To be cancelled
3      To be corrected
4      Processed
5      Rejected
```

User can create a new status or add translation for other language. The question is how to design tables and how to store translations for other languages?

For now I have a few approaches

1) create table `Languages` with all supported languages. Create table `Translations`

```
  Id   LanguageId  Key              Value
  ------------------------------------------------
  1    en          NotProcessed     Not processed
  2    pl          NotProcessed     Nie przetworzony
  3    de          NotProcessed     Nicht verarbeitet
  4    en          ToBeCancelled    To be cancelled
  5    de          ToBeCancelled    Zu stornieren
```

the status table will be

```
    Id     Name                   TranslationKey
    ----------------------------------------------
    1      Not processed          NotProcessed        
    2      To be cancelled        ToBeCancelled
```

then using according to language select proper translations that will show to user.

2) do not create Translations table, but add column

```
  Id     Name                   Translations
    ----------------------------------------------
    1      Not processed          en:Not processed;pl:Nie przetworzony;de:Nicht verarbeitet      
    2      To be cancelled        en:To be cancelled;de:Zu stornieren
```

What do you think about it? I don't know how to keep translations for my entities, may be there are some reliable ways. Please suggest.

Comment: I'm not a fan of using Database-based Localization. But if I have to, I would choose the first one because it is using a table that's normalized and  more efficient.

Comment: See also [an open source implementation](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreLocalization/blob/0f7361bf5951fead877a9ddd36bd3f478764e0a2/src/Localization.SqlLocalizer/DbStringLocalizer/LocalizationRecord.cs#L5-L14), they almost use the first approach too.

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar to approach no.1 by creating languages table and translations tables. But the translations tables are entity based, that's mean each entity type has its own entity translation type as well.

The entity translation holds all localizable fields (e.g. Title, Body), and the main entity holds non-localized fields (e.g. publish date, etc.)

```cs
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ArticleTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleTranslation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }

}
```

You may also use `virtual` keyword to support lazy loading of related translations or main entity.