# Recommended way to store globalized data model for dotnet application

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I would like to implement a set of data models that will also store its globalized content that the content could be displayed at .NET MVC and dotnet core application by the request culture, however, I cannot find the related resources/keyword for such purpose, below is the example models and any keywords/suggestion will be appreciated

```cs
public interface Article {
    string ArticleId { get; }
    string Title { get; }
    string Content { get; }
}

public interface CulturedArticle {
    string ArticleId { get; }
    string Culture { get; } // -- e.g. en or jp

    string Title { get; }
    string Content { get; }
}
```

---

Edit 1:

It seems ugly if I do the following, is finding a better way for this purpose

```cs
...

var article = this.GetRequestedArticle(request);
var cultureName = this.GetCultureName(request);

var culturedArticle = this.GetCulturedArticle(
    article.ArticleId,
    cultureName
);

return culturedArticle ?? article;

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously I was using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59781649/5519026) that implements one-to-many relationship, where the main entity has a relation to multiple localized entities. It is easy to implement when you have few models. But the problem was you should create all the fields that needs to be localized, and then create custom controller/view for handling translating of each model. And that means a lot of work to do if there are too many models.

Currently I'm testing a new approach, it is harder to implement but I found it much flexible when I have too many models.

Instead of creating the localized model with all fields, I created a similar structure for all localized models, I keep only the property name and its localized value with some relational fields to the main entity and culture. The new approach allowed to use only one view to handle translating every kind of entity local, because all implements the same interface.

Below is a summary of what I have done.

- I created an interface for localizable models:

```cs
public interface ILocalizedPropertyResource<T>
    where T : class
{
    // The property name from the main entity
    string PropertyName { get; set; }

    // Localized content
    string Value { get; set; }

    int EntityId { get; set; }
    T Entity { get; set; }

    string CultureName { get; set; }
    Culture Culture { get; set; }
}
```

- Then I created a custom attrbiute named `[LocalizeAttribute]`, it has nothing special, just will be applied to the localizable entity properties.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class LocalizeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public LocalizeAttribute() { }
}
```

- Then I created the models and applied the `Localize` attribute as below:

```cs
public string Article
{
    public int Article { get; set; }
    
    [Localize]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Localize]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ArticleLocal> Locals { get; set; }
}
```

- Then, created the local model of article:

```cs
public class ArticleLocal : ILocalizedPropertyResource<Article>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
        
    // This will hold the localizable property name
    // e.g. "Title" or "Content"
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        
    // This will hold the localized value
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public Article Entity { get; set; }

    // relation to cultures table        
    public string CultureName { get; set; }
    public Culture Culture { get; set; }
}
```

- And using reflection, I do check for the properties that has `[Localize]` attribute to dynamically create the translating form that save the values using one view for all models.

So with the new approach I have the main entity, and a collection of localized properties that easily can be included and filtered.

The work still in progress with the new approach, but as mentioned at the beginning, the new approach saved me a lot of time and effort.